# How to display and remove values in dictionary which holds duplicate keys

Tags: java, android-studio

In this program I want to display (textview) as Banana as the key value is. And I want to remove that key value 2 which holds banana. and i want to display (textview2) as Orange .Is there any alterative there? Could u give me a solution to obtain this? Thanks in advance

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 2;

Hashtable<Integer, String> my_dict = new Hashtable <Integer, String>();

my_dict.put(a, "Apple");
my_dict.put(b, "Banana");
my_dict.put(c, "Orange");
my_dict.put(d, "Grapes");

textView.setText(my_dict.get(1));//displays Apple
my_dict.remove(1);//removes Apple

textView2.setText(my_dict.get(2));//displays Grapes
my_dict.remove(2);//removes Grapes

textView3.setText(my_dict.get(2));//displays Banana
my_dict.remove(2);//removes Banana
```

But i dont want to alter that  duplicate keys. I want to iterate through each values of key and i want to get that datas which is stored in that key ...and i want to delete that key and value ...and after i want to check for another. (In this case)

Comment: Putting 2 as "Orange" will replace the older value "Banana", do you require to have two values with single key?

Comment: Hashtable does not accept duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [HashTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) maintains the uniqueness of keys i.e. when you will try to add an element with the existing key, the old value will be replaced with the new one. You can understand it with your own example given below:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        int c = 3;
        int d = 2;

        Hashtable<Integer, String> my_dict = new Hashtable <Integer, String>();

        my_dict.put(a, "Apple");
        my_dict.put(b, "Banana");
        my_dict.put(c, "Orange");
        my_dict.put(d, "Grapes");

        System.out.println(my_dict);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{3=Orange, 2=Grapes, 1=Apple}
```

As you can see, `Grape` has replaced `Banana` because it has the same key as that of `Banana`.

If you have a requirement to keep both `Grape` and `Banana` with the same id/key, you can implement your custom type something like:

```
class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    //Constructors, getters and setters 
}
```

And then, add the instances of `Item` to a `List` e.g.

```
List <Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
list.add(new Item(1, "Apple"));
list.add(new Item(2, "Banana"));
list.add(new Item(3, "Orange"));
list.add(new Item(2, "Grape"));
```

You can create some utility methods (an example is given below) to retrieve the required item from the `List`.

```
public Item getItemByName(List<Item> list, String itemName) {
    Item item = null;
    for(Item e: list){
        if(e.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(itemName)){
            item = e;
            break;
        }
    }
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Ok bro ..thanks .. and how to retrieve those values from list

Comment: @Abilash - You are most welcome. I've added a utility method for an example. You can create some other method as per your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Thanks bro ..and can u say how to learn depth of this like java codings and android studio...

Comment: You are most welcome. Learning to program efficiently requires practice and challenging ourselves. You already seem to be on the right track. Doing things, making mistakes, asking questions - all these help you learn faster. If you continue all these things, believe me, you will be a different programmer after six months.

Comment: Thanks for all bro ..and i have requested u in LINKEDIn ...plse accept for my future helps